# Передать данные на виджет с activity

Tags: android, android-widgets

Как передать данные с Activity на виджет? Ни где не могу найти как можно данные на виджет передать, что для этого использовать?

Comment: Используйте Intent с BroadcastReceiver для приема данных

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему я не догадался, это смешно даже. Но проблема решена. На самом деле мне нужно пересылать только номер позиции с ArrayList, а для этого можно добавить переменную в классе виджета и добавить setter().

```
public class WriteNotes extends AppWidgetProvider {

private static int position;

public static void setPosition(int position) {
    WriteNotes.position = position;
}
...
```

А в самом классе вызвать данный метод.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    try {
        int position = ((NotesAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).getPosition();

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.move:
                WriteNotes.setPosition(position);
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```